# Is it possible to replicate the _users database in CouchDB?

Tags: replication, couchdb

Is it possible to configure replication between the **"_users"** database on two instances of CouchDB? (currently using 1.4)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can replicate the _users database in Couch, in this respect, it's no different than any other database.